# AAD Claims UPN vs On-Premise AD UPN

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, upn

I thought `UserPrincipalName` (UPN) are single valued per user in the Directory, but when I run an LDAP query for a specific user, I get the UPN: `AO0S0020@mydomain.local`,

And when running an OAuth (OpenId Connect) authorization against Azure AD (which is synced using `AD Connect`), I see that the claims UPN for the same user: `nati@mydomain.com`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concept of [Alternate login id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configuring-alternate-login-id).

It seems your Azure AD connect is configured with alternate login id. Thus the difference.

Comment: I tried to fetch the `AlternateLoginID` attribute from the LDAP, but it does now exist.

Comment: AlternateLoginID is configured in ADFS and ADConnect, not in AD. Usually, it points to the email AD property.

Comment: I would get the guid (or OID) from AD for nati@mydomain.com and then look for this oid guid value in another field in LDAP.

Comment: @SqlSurfer the OID in Azure AD is completely disconnected from your on-premises world. So there is nothing to match with it. The link from cloud to on-prem is source anchor. And its configuration varies and can be changed (Azure AD Connect settings).